# Ruby and RSpec - Test fails when expected output is the same as the method

Tags: ruby, rspec

I know I am missing something simple here. I want to write a test that checks if an array of array has been outputted. The test keeps failing but what the test expects is the same that the method is giving.

connect4.rb

```
class Board
  attr_accessor :board
  def make_and_print_board
    grid = Array.new(6) { Array.new(6)}
    p grid
  end
end
```

connect4_spec.rb

```
require  './lib/connect4'


RSpec.describe Board do
  let (:new_board) {Board.new}
  it "prints board" do
    expect{new_board.make_and_print_board}.to output(
      Array.new(6) { Array.new(6)}
    ).to_stdout
  end
end
```

This is the error...

```
 1) Board prints board
     Failure/Error:
           expect{new_board.make_and_print_board}.to output(
             Array.new(6) { Array.new(6)}

           ).to_stdout

       expected block to output [[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]] to stdout, but output "[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]\n[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]\n[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]\n[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]\n[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]\n[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]\n"
```

What am I missing here? Why isn't it passing? How can I get this test to pass?

Comment: you're outputting a string representation of an array of array's and then telling RSpec you expect it to output an. array of array's...need to tell RSpec to expect a string (or regex to match a string against)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write this test is to be verbose about your expectation. Test the exact value of what you expect ii to give. `p` will output a new line so write this way.

```
RSpec.describe Board do
  let (:new_board) {Board.new}
  it 'prints board' do
    p_output = "[[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]]\n"

    expect{new_board.make_and_print_board}.to output(p_output).to_stdout
  end
end
```

But you might want to add this spec if you care more about the internals:

```
  it 'it outputs a 6 x 6 2d array' do
    expect( new_board.make_and_print_board ).to match_array Array.new(6) { Array.new(6)} 
  end
```